# Storing Application context in SharedPreferences when app crashes

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, applicationcontext

Currently im storing all of my users information and there friends information inside a class i have created called `userInfoCore` that extends `Application` so i can store the values in the Context. When my app crashes it gets rid of al those values and my users are forced to relogin, so i would like to store them in SharedPreferences to be grabbed again in the `onCreate` of my `MainActivity`.

I know how to store them, thats not the issue. The issue is i dont want to overcrowd my code with repetitive code and put the storing methods in all the `onDestroy`'s of all my Activities, and i cant `@Override onDestroy` in my `userInfoCore` class because its not an Activity i imagine?

Some insite would be great. Thank!

EDIT:

Ive found out that this line in the android manifest is causing my Application Context data to be destroyed even when the user presses the home screen. `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

My thoughts are YES i could store them in the `onPause` or do what @CommonsWare suggested. However like i said, i dont want to have to do all of that. If i can find the root of the cause of the issue... which i have. (The singleInstance in manifest) then i would be much happier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some insite would be great.

Update your persistent store when the data changes. A custom `Application` subclass, like any singleton, should only be treated as a cache or other transient spot for data. If you care about the values, persist them, at the point when the data is changed.

Comment: Im new to Android development so bare with me, what is the persistent store and how can i achieve that? I know i asked for insite but maybe i should of asked for insite and a link or some example code.

Comment: BTW love the work you do in the community. Great job working that brain of yours :D

Comment: @AaronRussell: "what is the persistent store" -- a file. Or a database. Or `SharedPreferences`. Or "the cloud".

Comment: Ohh... i see, well that makes sense now then. I'll do that, one more thing... this line in my AndroidManifest is whats causing my Context data to be destroyed... its not allowing it to hold it properly... `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` what can i do to solve this? I need it for my Twitter oAuth (twitter4j)

Comment: @AaronRussell: "I need it for my Twitter oAuth (twitter4j)" -- I am not aware that this would be a requirement. I would recommend asking a separate StackOverflow question to get clarification on that point.

Comment: I need it so that my WebView intent that im calling to have them login receives a callback with there tokens verified. I dont' want to have to open a separate question, i feel like this is the right place as this whole question is based off of why i cant keep my values and how to. I'll edit this answer to more lean toward the new issue on why im not keep those values. This line in the android manifest is causing it to delete even the Application Context when the user presses the home screen.

Comment: Considering that your answer does satisfy my issue, storing the value in persistent storage. I'll accept your answer. At least until someone can provide me with a way to solve my manifest issue. Im just afraid to open another question beausee ive had so many closed my mods that were claimed i already asked that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good argument for using the Model-View-Presenter (or Model-View-Controller) pattern.   By separating your Model (domain data and procedures) from your View and Presenter (Layout and Activity respectively) you only have to write the Store logic once.

Then you have two choices: either do as @CommonsWare suggests, have the model write itself whenever it changes, or add a simple call in each Application's onPause (onDestroy is too late! It may never get called.) to the model to tell it to save itself.

Note: the model can accept a context as a construction parameter for use in finding a shared preferences, or it can create it's own named preferences using the PreferenceManager

Comment: I agree with the onDestroy not getting called all the time, thats sad that it does that. i had a issue with that and had to put something in the onPause awhile back and learned my lesson on that one. Your second suggestion is basically what im trying to avoid.